# How Can I Add Plugins To Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins

I'm not exactly sure if I can ask this question, but I definitely need an answer for this.  I'm working on a Rails project- a forum- and I want to know how I can implement 'plugins' in it.

Basically, I want someone who doesn't know a lot about programming or ruby on rails to be able to add functionality to my forums (assuming they cloned my forum onto their server).  The general ideas are

- The plugins would have their own directory, like `plugins`, and would be separated in this directory by the plugin name.
- I would be able to run a command like `rake forum:plugins:install some-url` that would download and install the plugin for them
- The plugins would be able to modify/add assets, as well as change views, controllers, or models
- The plugins do not change the code of the actual forum

When starting the project, I had the idea in my head that I could just apply a patch or two that would install plugins, but that would be terrible when the user would have to upgrade the forums.

So, my questions are:

1. How can I implement my plugins as outlined above?
2. Is it a good idea to do this using rails?

Again, I'm not sure if these questions are allowed, but I guess I'll find out.

Just to clarify, I'm looking for a system akin to SMF's package feature (which allows you to import and install plugins/packages on the forum software itself). I'm not looking for plugins for rails itself, but rather the application running on rails (the forums).

**TL;DR**: I'm looking for a way to make a modification to a rails app without modifying the source code.  I am *NOT* looking for rails 2 plugins, or rubygems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since the time I asked the question, a friend pointed me in a direction.  As a plugin, I wanted it to be able to put code into the forums, but as a separate codebase; as in, none of it goes into the actual code.  My friend pointed me to [`Rails::Engine`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html), which at first didn't seem like what I needed.

With the `Rails::Engine`, I could create a separate directory, populate it with my 'addons' or 'plugins', and the Application wouldn't be affected by each separate one.  It would also make creating addons or plugins easy.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails, most plugins are usually implemented as [gems](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/1).

From the above link:

> A gem is a packaged Ruby application or library. It has
>   a name (e.g. rake) and a version (e.g. 0.4.16).

I would do that instead. Gems are by far the most common way of creating functionality that you'd want to exist in multiple applications.

Also: [How to make your own gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/)

Comment: Ok, that's not what I meant by 'plugin'; what I mean is user X downloads the forums, and wants to add plugin that user Y created for it- if user Y were to put his plugin in a gem, It would still not solve the problem of the third bullet, which was the plugins would be able to modify assets, and change views, controllers, and models.

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten answer:

After reading your request again I have a better answer.  Why not just use github for your app where you have a master repository and accept patches to it?  If people are tech savvy enough to be editing models, controllers, views, they should be savvy enough to create a patch request through github.  That way you can approve them easily too.

Comment: The idea is 1) I'm assuming they're not (second paragraph) that tech-savvy, or don't know enough to be editing the forums 2) I want to be able to separate the forums from plugins and 3) Not pollute the forum's code so that it is easily upgradable.

Answer (score 0):

[Feature Flags](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/697-rolling-out-with-feature-flags) can help you let you users turn features on and off, though the code need to be in the app on deploy.

Answer (score -2):

To install new plugin:

```
rails install PLUGIN [plugin_name]
```